# Crash on iOS 10.3.1 when inserting a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios10, uicollectionviewlayout

I am moving across some content across from a different application, and doing so required me to move a NIB. Moving this NIB has caused a crash on iOS 10 which was occurring every time - this crash had no search results on stack overflow or much other information online.

I am reloading the cell using this code:

```
collectionView?.performBatchUpdates({
    collectionView?.insertItems(at: [ indexPath ])
}, completion: nil)
```

Specifically, when inserting the collection view cell, this is the error:

```
    * thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
        frame #0: 0x0000000105015acb libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 11
        frame #1: 0x0000000104c5506f Foundation`-[NSLayoutAnchor nsli_lowerIntoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:] + 376
        frame #2: 0x0000000104b21c11 Foundation`-[NSLayoutConstraint _lowerIntoExpression:reportingConstantIsRounded:] + 99
        frame #3: 0x0000000104b1b56e Foundation`-[NSLayoutConstraint _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] + 121
        frame #4: 0x000000010721fc71 UIKit`__57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 + 454
        frame #5: 0x0000000104b2182b Foundation`-[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] + 155
        frame #6: 0x000000010721fa84 UIKit`__57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke + 604
        frame #7: 0x000000010721f800 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:] + 223
        frame #8: 0x000000010721e933 UIKit`-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] + 447
        frame #9: 0x0000000107211499 UIKit`-[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] + 130
        frame #10: 0x0000000106917909 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 209
        frame #11: 0x000000010690ab96 UIKit`__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 151
        frame #12: 0x000000010690aa7d UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 828
        frame #13: 0x000000010691aa0a UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1927
        frame #14: 0x000000010718aef7 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _addControlledSubview:atZIndex:] + 571
        frame #15: 0x000000010718dec0 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 1881
        frame #16: 0x000000010718d761 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:] + 35
        frame #17: 0x00000001071ac194 UIKit`__51-[UICollectionView _viewAnimationsForCurrentUpdate]_block_invoke.1941 + 564
        frame #18: 0x00000001071a95bb UIKit`-[UICollectionView _viewAnimationsForCurrentUpdate] + 5141
        frame #19: 0x00000001071aebf3 UIKit`__71-[UICollectionView _updateWithItems:tentativelyForReordering:animator:]_block_invoke.2012 + 197
        frame #20: 0x000000010691308e UIKit`+[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 90
        frame #21: 0x00000001071ad82d UIKit`-[UICollectionView _updateWithItems:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 3856
        frame #22: 0x00000001071a7b33 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 17030
        frame #23: 0x00000001071b01cd UIKit`-[UICollectionView _endUpdatesWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 71
        frame #24: 0x00000001071b0514 UIKit`-[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:animator:] + 437
        frame #25: 0x00000001071b033c UIKit`-[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:] + 91
        frame #26: 0x00000001071b02be UIKit`-[UICollectionView _performBatchUpdates:completion:invalidationContext:] + 74
        frame #27: 0x00000001071b0213 UIKit`-[UICollectionView performBatchUpdates:completion:] + 53
      * frame #28: 0x00000001046f44be IndexListSampleApp`closure #1 in RemoteIndexListContent.willDisplay(result=success, self=0x00006080000d0fb0, collectionView=0x00007f924588e600, indexPath=2 indices) at RemoteIndexListContent.swift:98
        frame #29: 0x00000001046f464d IndexListSampleApp`partial apply for closure #1 in RemoteIndexListContent.willDisplay(itemAtIndexPath:cell:collectionView:) at RemoteIndexListContent.swift:0
        frame #30: 0x000000010458f528 IndexListSampleApp`specialized closure #1 in RemoteLiveEventTileContentProvider.loadContent(fixtures=<unavailable>, self=<unavailable>, completion=0x00000001046f45d0 IndexListSampleApp`partial apply forwarder for closure #1 (Result.Result<IndexListFoundation.IndexListContent>) -> () in IndexListFoundation.RemoteIndexListContent.willDisplay(itemAtIndexPath: Foundation.IndexPath, cell: __ObjC.UICollectionViewCell, collectionView: __ObjC.UICollectionView) -> () at RemoteIndexListContent.swift) at RemoteLiveEventTileContentProvider.swift:49 [opt]
        frame #31: 0x000000010458cc0b IndexListSampleApp`partial apply for closure #1 in RemoteLiveEventTileContentProvider.loadContent(completion:) [inlined] closure #1 (Swift.Optional<Swift.Array<Core.Fixture>>, Swift.Optional<Swift.Error>) -> () in LiveEvent.RemoteLiveEventTileContentProvider.loadContent(completion: (Result.Result<IndexListFoundation.IndexListContent>) -> ()) -> () at RemoteLiveEventTileContentProvider.swift:0 [opt]
```

This only happens on iOS 10.2.1 -> 10.3.1 - OK on iOS 9 and iOS 11. I am using Xcode 9.0.1, the crash is also reproducible on Xcode 9.2.

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: @Skywalker this is a NIB issue, I can show the code I use to reload but it's fairly vanilla UICollectionView

Comment: Nvm if you fixed already

Comment: @Skywalker I added a code sample, I wanted to make sure no-one got stuck on the same problem as me! It was quite annoying and not very easy to debug

Comment: Also seen as `"[UILayoutGuide nsli_lowerIntoExpression:withCoefficient:forConstraint:]"`

Answer (score 3):

The fix was quite simple. I had `"Use Safe Area Layout Guides"` ticked - this clearly has an underlying issue on iOS 10.2.1 -> 10.3.1. Unticking this option resolves the crash!

[image: use safe layout image link]